# Setting up Mercurial push from UAT to PROD

Tags: mercurial

We have a system right now that runs Mercurial which allows us to push code from DEV to UAT... I need to add the ability to push from UAT to PROD.  I'm not used to Mercurial and from what I understand in order to have the ability to push to a directory you need to have cloned your current directory from that original.  Is that correct or is there a way for me to setup UAT to push to PROD without erasing UAT and creating a new UAT based off of a clone of PROD??

I hope that was a clear explanation, I can't think of a way to explain it better.

Comment: You need to clone PROD from UAT, not the other way round.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit `[paths]` section in the `.hg/hgrc` file to point to any related repository that you want.  By related, I mean that the pointed-to repository has been cloned from the other (actually, you can point to any repository, but if they're not related you'll get errors on the push).  If you clone B from A, B will already have a `default` path that points to A.

In your case, edit the `.hg/hgrc` in the UAT repo to add lines like:

```
[paths]
prod = <URL or filesystem path of prod>
```

See `hg help paths` or http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#paths for more information.

Comment: So you're saying all I need to do is edit that path, then I can push from UAT to PROD?

Comment: @webnet: if PROD was cloned from UAT, then yes.

Comment: I see.... I'll give this a shot later today and let you know if it works, thanks!